# How to update bar chart automatically when a data is added?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, widget, bar-chart

I would like to update the bar chart automatically when a new data is being submitted by the user. I do not want to use RefreshIndicator because in this case the user should pull until the data is updated. I want to update the bar chart without pull up, I would like to make it automatically when the user adds new data. Please find my following code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build() Chart');
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 6,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        child: BarChart(
                          isPlaying ? randomData() : mainBarData(),
                          swapAnimationDuration: animDuration,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: const Color(0xff0f4a3c),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                        if (isPlaying) {
                          refreshState();
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }  

List<BarChartGroupData> showingGroups() => List.generate(7, (i) {
        print("Switchhhhhh");
        switch (i) {
          case 0:
            return makeGroupData(0, total_Monday, isTouched: i == touchedIndex);
          case 1:
            return makeGroupData(1, total_Tuesday,
                isTouched: i == touchedIndex);
          case 2:
            return makeGroupData(2, total_Wednesday,
                isTouched: i == touchedIndex);
          case 3:
            return makeGroupData(3, total_Thursday,
                isTouched: i == touchedIndex);
          case 4:
            return makeGroupData(4, total_Friday, isTouched: i == touchedIndex);
          case 5:
            return makeGroupData(5, total_Saturday,
                isTouched: i == touchedIndex);
          case 6:
            return makeGroupData(6, total_Sunday, isTouched: i == touchedIndex);
          default:
            return null;
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without all of the code, it's hard to say what some of your functions do, and whether you are using a Stateless or Stateful widget, but I'm guessing `randomData` and `mainBarData` generate your bar graph.

To achieve the dynamic behavior you're seeking, you need your underlying data to be stateful. This can be accomplished in a number of ways, but the simplest, built-in way, would be to use a StatefulWidget to mutate your data source. Then, make sure your functions for generating the graph from the underlying data are in the build method so that the result of those functions is updated when the underlying data is changed.

[Here is an example of a StatefulWidget in action](https://googleflutter.com/flutter-add-item-to-listview-dynamically/), instead being used to add items to a list. The concepts should be applicable to your situation.

Related: [how to make dynamic chart in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040718/how-to-make-dynamic-chart-in-flutter)